# Basis for a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need to calculate the basis for
$$W = \lbrace (a,b,c,d) \: : \:  a+b+c = 0 \rbrace.$$ 
I find it hard to understand how does the fact that d is not part of the equation effects the basis.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to find a basis of the vector space, not for the group.

Comment: sorry, edited. W is obviously a subspace as it is a set of  solutions for homogenous equations. in this case on equation

Comment: I tried to find the solution for a+b+c =0 and by that, i ended up with only 2 free variables, b and c. and avoided d as it is 0. or so.. that's why i am finding it hard. to sum it up I came up with a basis of two vectors ===> dim W = 2.

Comment: You only have one condition.  We can, for example, let $b,c,d$ be any numbers we like and then just compute $a$ using your equation.  Thus we have three independent degrees of freedom so...

Comment: so in that case the basis is {(0,0,0,1),(-1,0,1,0),(-1,1,0,0)} ?

Comment: I still do not get why is that so? d is always 0.. the (0,0,0,1) doesnt seem to makse sense being part of the basis

Comment: Your basis is good!  No problem with $d$.  As you (correctly) remark, $(0,0,0,1)$ is a perfectly good solution to your equation.

Comment: Just to stress:  your comment that "$d$ is always $0$" is false.  Indeed, $(0,0,0,d)$ satisfies $a+b+c=0$ regardless of the value of $d$.

Answer (score 1):

$W$ is the kernel of a non zero linear form. Therefore the dimension of $W$ as a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^4$ is $4-1=3$. So it suffices to find three independent vectors belonging to $W$

$(0,0,0,1)$ is an obvious element of $W$

$(1,-1,0,0)$ and $(0,-1,1,0)$ are two other vectors.

The three vectors are independent therefore a basis.

Answer (score 0):

If
$$W = \left\{ (a,b,c,d)  \,\middle|\, a+b+c=0 \right\}$$
then $W$ consists of all vectors of the form $(a,b,c,d)$ where $d \in \mathbb{R}$ can be anything but where the first the three elements are bounded by the condition $a+b+c=0$.

To see what this means, you can solve this equation for one of the variables, say $c=-b-a$, and substitute. An arbitrary element of $W$ is thus of the form $(a,b,-a-b,d)$. But this means all these elements can be written as a linear combination of three vectors ($a,b,d \in \mathbb{R}$):
$$(a,b,-a-b,d) = a\,\color{blue}{(1,0,-1,0)}+b\,\color{blue}{(0,1,-1,0)}+d\,\color{blue}{(0,0,0,1)}$$
So now clearly, the vectors in blue span $W$. If these three vectors are also linearly independent, you have found a basis as well. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score -2):

Note that in the definition of $W$ you've given, $a+b+c = 0$ is best understood as a **constraint** on the 4-tuple $(a,b,c,d)$.

That is, there aren't any explicit constraints on $d$, so conceivably it can be whatever it wants.

Usually, linear algebra deals with real numbers, so it's my guess that $d\in R$, but that's not in the definition you've given, and so is just a guess on my part.